# How to use sqli connection in shortcode in function.php file -wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, wordpress

I am working on WordPress site. I have issue when I make sqli connection in shordcode so it does not work some time it shows blank page and some time it mar my website styling.

This is conn code that I use in shortcode in function.php file:

```
<?php
$options = "select * from options";//select query for viewing users.  
$run=mysqli_query($conn,$options);//here run the sql query.  

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
{  
    $percent = $row[1] ."%";
    $percent2 = $row[2] ."%";
    $percent3 = $row[3] ."%";
?>
```

When I add that code, it show this:

[image]

and when I remove it, it shows me blank page.

Comment: Use wordpress prepared statement, Why are you using mysqli_query ?

Comment: Brah, u gotta at least google how to use WordPress. They have functions to retrieve these values from their native db tables, like options, postmeta etc